# join count per chatroom

Tags: mysql, join, count, chat

i have tried different join examples from w3c site, but could not solve my problem.

All i could get working was:

```
SELECT *  
FROM chatters_online 
WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(),datumtijd )) < 300
```

But i want is a count of chatters per chatroom: room1(12),room12(2) etc.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `chatters_online` (
  `room` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `datumtijd` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `chatterID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `nick` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_index` (`room`,`nick`),
  KEY `room` (`room`),
  KEY `nick` (`nick`),
  KEY `datumtijd` (`datumtijd`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `chatrooms` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `roomname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `moderator` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `roomname` (`roomname`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=18 ;
```

What i am looking for is the needed SQL for a count per chatroom.

Comment: You haven't described your problem.

Comment: Yes i did, But i want is a count of chatters per chatroom: room1(12),room12(2) etc. but apperently i was not clear enough. I meant the sql i need for my wanted result. i will edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JOIN` and `GROUP BY` should give you the required results

```
select CR.roomname, count(CO.chatterID) as ChattersCount
FROM chatrooms CR
JOIN chatters_online CO
on CO.room = CR.id
GROUP BY CR.roomname
```

Comment: Thanks! I only added WHERE TIME_TO_SEC( TIMEDIFF( NOW( ) , CO.datumtijd ) ) <7 to ONLY get active chatters. offline chatters are deleted via cron, which is not every few seconds:) So i need to make the sql select the online ones. Thank you again!